# Why won't Laravel pass my variable to blade template?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5.2. In routes.php, I have:

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    $events = App\Event::get();
    return view('test', $events);
});
```

In test.blade.php, I have:

```
<?php print_r($events) ?>
```

And I get:

> ErrorException in ....php line 11:
>   Undefined variable: events (View: .../test.blade.php)

My get() statement is working properly (print_r($events) works in routes.php). Why isn't it getting passed to the blade template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the data correctly. Try this instead:

```
return view('test', ['events' => $events]);
```

You have other options too. For example:

```
return view('test', compact('events'));

return view('test')->with(['events' => $events]);
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views

Comment: Just becareful linking people to 'master' docs as that is the unreleased next version of laravel.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Kinda wonky that you have to pass it that way, no?

Answer (score 1):

```
return view('test', ['events' => $events]);
```

you can also display value like this in blade (for testing)

```
{{ dd($events) }}
```